# Better alternative to time.sleep() for discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, delay

I am a new developer trying to learn by making a Discord bot with python. For a part of my bot, I want it to reply to a message, wait 10 seconds and then delete both the reply and the referenced message. Instinctively, I used time.sleep() for the delay, however, this puts my entire bot on hold for 10 seconds, so I tried looking for an alternative with no luck. Any helpful code with explanations for the changes is very much appreciated!

Current code:

```
# Delete the referred to message
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    # <A bunch of other irrelevant code>
    if successCounter == 1:
        await reaction.message.reply("Image successfully added!")
        time.sleep(10)
        await reaction.message.delete()
```

```
# Delete the "Image successfully added!" message
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == botID:
        if message.reference is not None:
            time.sleep(10)
            await message.delete()
```

Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep()`, `time.sleep` is somehow outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

asyncio has a function called sleep() too, which does work asynchronously. So just use `await asyncio.sleep(10)` instead of `time.sleep()`